# Sun: When its closest and when its farther away?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life, sun

If the sun is closest to the North American Hemisphere in the winter than it is in the summer, why doesn't our faces and hands tan and/or blister quicker? Please provide two hyperlink sources with your answer.  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the reason for the seasons?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26785/whats-the-reason-for-the-seasons)

Comment: I initially marked this as a duplicate, but JiK pointed out that the light intensity incident normal to a plane (like a face pointing towards the sun) does not change across the seasons (ignoring atmospheric loss). So this isn't really a question about what causes the seasons, but rather a question of whether the light volumetric energy density is actually lower in winter.

Comment: The sun is, of course, closer to ***all*** the hemispheres of earth in the Northern hemisphere winter...

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114243/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earth is only about 3% closer to the Sun during the northern-hemisphere winter, which means its intensity would only increase by a maximum of about 6%. There is more atmosphere to block out the UV rays that cause tanning and burns due to the shallower angle of incidence. You tend to wear more clothing (gloves, scarf, etc) that blocks the rays. It's cold, so I doubt a lot of people spend a lot of time outside just sitting around with their faces and hands towards the Sun and it would still take some time to get a noticeable tan with only a 6% increase in intensity and a decrease in the UV band from the longer path through the atmosphere.

TLDR: Many possible reasons contribute.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the sun is shooting the light at such a small angle that the light have to travel trough the atmosphere for a longer distance. And the atmosphere will decrease the luminosity of the sun. If we could move with the earth in the outer space without rotation, then we would find that the sun is flying upward and downward, drawing a sine wave in the sky. And in winter, the sun will shoot the surface of the earth at a small angel.

Comment: @JohnRennie then make your own answer

Comment: @JohnRennie The question is about the tanning of our faces and hands, and I cannot see why the intensity (power per square metre) on our faces and hands would be any lower.

Comment: @JohnRennie Isn't the area where the sunlight spread all the same during a whole year?

Comment: This answer is either wrong, or very badly worded.

Comment: @JiK: The intensity (power per square meter at Earth's surface) is much lower in winter than in summer. That's the whole point of seasons. That's why winter is cold.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: So it's the angle of refractivity of the light.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Winter is colder because the intensity on the ground is much lower (and thus ground warms the air less). The intensity on the ground is lower because the ground (or sun) is "tilted" such that the power is spread over larger area than in the summer. However, my face does not lie flat on the ground so I don't think this argument can be applied here.

Comment: Ok, I think this is starting to look like a discussion on something else than the answer, so probably somebody should give another answer discussing this.

Comment: @JiK: Hmm, you're right about it not causing any difference for a plane normal to the incident rays (like a face pointing towards the sun). I'll retract my close-as-duplicate vote.