# Seasons of Earths Orbit

Tags: orbital-motion

I live in Northern hemisphere. Closer to the sun during winter. Planet traveling fastest in orbit. Does this mean a shorter winter season compared to the south?

Comment: Distance from the sun doesn't cause seasons. see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26785/whats-the-reason-for-the-seasons?rq=1

Comment: There is a difference of a few days http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2011/12/the-earth-is-hottest-when-it-is-furthest-from-the-sun-on-its-orbit-not-when-it-is-closest/

Answer (score 0):

Seasons are *mostly* caused by Earth axis inclination relative to Sun. The closest point of the Earth's elliptical trajectory does not coincide with the winter nor summer solstice.

Accidentally, we live in an epoch when Earth is closest to Sun in January, thus the northern temperature swing is a bit milder than the southern.

However the Sun's tidal force causes the Earth's rotation axis to rotate with a precession period of ca. 26000 years. The "year" as we know it differs from the Earth's orbital period by ca. 20 minutes (1/26000 of year).

To your question, I conjecture that the effect of Earth passing its near-to-Sun portion of orbit faster would most affect the climate in our epoch on April (January+3 months) and October (January-3 months), making both a bit colder. The deviations from sinusoidal Earth-Sun distance are however probably negligible.